# How to guarantee that camel logs in ASCII text not in decimals?

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-camel, logback

In one of my camel route, i use camel's log eip as:

```
from("direct:someSourceWithBodyOfTypeMap")
    .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
    .to("direct:logHandler");


// on a separate route builder
from("direct:logForFilebeat")
    .convertBodyTo(String.class, "UTF-8")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "jsonLogger","${body}");
```

This route's purpose is to marshal a source  of type Map to json and log the body which is later on picked up by a log aggregator. Im using logback for the logging. a portion of the logback-spring.xml looks like this:

```
   <appender name="JSON_TX" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
      <file>${BASE_LOG_PATH}/json.log</file>
      <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
         <fileNamePattern>${BASE_LOG_PATH}/json.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
         <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
            <maxFileSize>100MB</maxFileSize>
         </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
      </rollingPolicy>
      <encoder>
         <charset>UTF-8</charset>
         <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
      </encoder>
   </appender>
   <appender name="ASYNC_JSON_TX" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
      <appender-ref ref="JSON_TX" />
   </appender>
   <logger name="jsonLogger" level="INFO">
      <appender-ref ref="ASYNC_FILEBEAT_TX" />
   </logger>
```

In a normal flow, it gets properly logged as a json string like:

```
{"id":2456,"name":"foo","gender":"MALE"}
```

but there are instances that it gets logged as:

```
123 34 105 100 34 58 50 52 53 54 44 34 110 97 109 101 34 58 34 102 111 111 34 44 34 103 101 110 100 101 114 34 58 34 77 65 76 69 34 125
```

This decimals logs are generated when there are messages being processed by the route and the spring-boot up is triggered for shutdown. (I was able to replicate this locally by placing a breakpoint into processor before the source route, then shutting down spring-boot app while messages are routed to 'someSourceWithBodyOfTypeMap'.)

How do i enforce that the what gets appended to the log file should be in ASCII Text format not in decimal? And what triggers the logs to be in decimal in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not decimals its because your message body is marshalled as a stream of bytes. You can convert the message body to a String first by adding `.convertBodyTo(String)` after the `marshal`, or specify that the logger should convert to string via `${bodyAs(String)}`.

Comment: i actually tested it beforehand with the .convertBodyTo(String.class,"UTF-8") before calling the log (but that time logger is on a separate route builder). I was able to produce the json string locally using the debugging i mentioned above but broke in production where there is a larger volume of data. I'll try it with '${bodyAs(String)}'

Comment: Just mind about streaming and empty body problem, see this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html